# Google Drive integration giving generic Xcode archive

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I have made a project where I have integrated BOX, Dropbox and Google Drive. Now everything is working fine in device. When making an archive its giving Generic Xcode Archive.

I have removed google drive totally and it works fine again.

However i need to add google Drive so I added it. Without opening the code this time, I have just added and Checked for archive. Same result.

Any help?

INFO: I have tried archiving without using device it gave linker error.

Comment: @Manic One I am facing issue while integrating google Drive SDK in my Xcode.It is not allowing me to import GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h Please help me

Comment: @iosdeveloper sorry for a late response. please check in this Blog:
http://innofied.com/google-drive-integration-in-ios-apps/